# some convenient note for random though or to-do list?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for some application that can let me write down some to-do list for the day/week/month, or some random thoughts, and also is easy to access (for example, it can be shown as an icon on the panel, which will expand to a window if I click it (it isn't necessary to be that way)) and is small and light software.

I may create a text file on the desktop for that purpose, but I have many text files on desktop already and I may mess them up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think [Tomboy](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy) it's what you're looking for:

```
sudo apt-get install tomboy
```

In order to have it integrated with the Unity Dash, you can also install:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-tomboy
```

Answer (score 1):

It may also be worth looking at Google Keep, as depending on your setup it may work in the way you require. It will also sync your notes across all your devices (that you can access Keep from - which is most).